# How did none of the Salamancas notice that Hector could be completely cured?

Tags: better-call-saul

In season 4, [Dr. Bruckner](https://breakingbad.fandom.com/wiki/Maureen_Bruckner) from Johns-Hopkins Hospital stated that it was possible to fully treat Hector to the point of full resumption of normal body functions such as talking and walking. How come none of the Salamancas e.g. Marco and Leonel disputed Hector's (IMO early discharge) from hospital until he was fully treated? I think it was a waste because it was possible for Hector's stroke to be fully treated.

Comment: Well, they didn't know. She said that to Gus, and he apparently made sure that they wouldn't hear about it.

Comment: Yeah, if only Hector could have got all his faculties back. The world really missed that guy.

Answer (score 2):

Given that, as Mithoron said, the doctor spoke with Gus not any Salamanca and even the doctor would not have said it was a sure thing, there is no reason for the medically unsophisticated, I assume, cousins or Lalo to assert that Hector required further treatment.

Comment: "...there is no reason for the medically unsophisticated, I assume, cousins or Lalo to assert that Hector required further treatment." Wouldn't it be worth a shot to pursue further treatment if a family member was ailing and a doctor said that there was a **possibility** of recovery from further treatment?

Comment: The doctor was in direct communication with Gus, not the silent Cousins who you must admit would have sounded odd having a conversation with the doctor. They would of course sure have had the money for any necessary treatment but accepted that what had happened had happened and nothing further could be done.

Comment: "...but accepted that what had happened had happened and nothing further could be done..." A nitpick - this looks like more of a fan theory or an opinion.

Comment: @user14773854: U asked if it would be worth a shot -- since the cousins and Lalo did nothing, it is clear that they accepted the situation. Lalo in particular is someone who does what he thinks needs to be done, even if it means killing innocents and those loyal to him. Since he did nothing, it is no fan theory but exactly his stance. Perhaps Gus conveyed to him that everything possible had been done and Lalo accepted this as, after all, it was Gus who had saved Hector's life in the first place.

Comment: What do you mean by “medically unsophisticated”? Do you just mean they are not doctors or medical professionals themselves?

Comment: @ToddWilcox: I am going out on a limb here but I would bet that the Cousins don't know much about history, biology, or science book or even the French they took. But they do, fortunately for them, know about shooting people and killing them with bladed weapons. Unusual childhoods had they, I think.

Comment: I think the real question here is why was it up to Gus to get Hector discharged from the hospital. I get that he was paying for the specialist so he could send her back. But the basic general treatment at the hospital was something the Salamncas could do for themselves. It cant be complications with the police either because Hector does not go back to Mexico. He seems to have just gone from the hospital to the retirement home